# Not able to see values of variables in Google Chrome while debugging Angular code

Tags: angular7

I am not able to see values of variables in **Google Chrome** while debugging **Angular code**.

Answer (score 0):

An update must have been pushed recently that is causing this.

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/22882968?hl=en
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16855096?hl=en

If you can download an update for chrome it should be fixed now